# Finding the maximum speed up of an application when using some number of cpus in parallel

Tags: performance, parallel-processing, parallelism-amdahl

Suppose that we have the following code:

```
int i,j;

for(i=0; i<20; i++)
   A[i] = A[i] + B[i];

for(j=0; j<8; j++){
   C[j] = C[j] + D[j];
   E[j] = E[j] + C[j];
}
```

Now let's assume that we have `14` identical CPUS that can be used to help us compute the final results in parallel.

What is the maximum speed up that we would get by using all the `14` cpus when executing the above code? Let's say that each operation(addition) takes `1` unit of time.

As I see it, the speed up is generally `Ts/Tp` where `Ts` is the time spent when using `1` cpu while `Tp` is the time spent when using all the cpus available.

In my example, we would have to spend `20 + 8*2 = 36` time units to execute the code with `1` cpu.

Then with `14` cpus, we could use `1` time unit to find the first `14` values of `A`. Then with `6` cpus we could use another `1` time unit to find the remaining `6` values of `A`.

While finding the remaining values of `A` we would use the other `8` cpus to find the `8` values of `C` and `E` by spending `2` time units.

So in total we would spend `1 + (1 || 2) = 1 + 2 = 3` time units, which means that the `speedup` would be `36/3 = 12`

**Is this correct? Can we use the cpus in a better way to achieve a better speed up? Also, would it be possible to somehow use the Amdahl's law to find the result much quicker?** Amdahl's law says that if `x` is the portion of the total code that can't run in parallel then the maximum speed up is `1/(x + (1 - x)/p)` where `p` is the number of cpus used, so in my case this number would be equal to `14`.

However I'm not sure how we can find the portion of our code that can' be run in parallel. If I decide to solve the following equation:

[image]

then `x = 1/78`. However how can I find this `x` by just looking at the code? If I decide to look at my problem more generally, the first loop which needs `20` time units can be run in parallel. However in the second loop, the operations inside the loop can't run in parallel, so out of the `16` time units, only the `8` can be run in parallel.

So the total amount of time that can run in parallel is `28`. So `x = 8/36`.

So we get from Amdahl law the following result(from wolframalpha):

[image]

but I found a `12` speed up by following the logic explained above. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

according to the following site 
http://www.futurechips.org/thoughts-for-researchers/parallel-programming-gene-amdahl-said.html
The number of CPUs should not be limited to 14, and you should take the size of your vectors as n. What we do with Amadahl's law is finding how well an algorithm scales and this limit is reached when p goes to infinity.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption about parallelizing this code in regads with amdahl's law is not right your code is sequential as amdahl law care about the enhancement of this part so while you are computing first loop only 14 out of 20 serial jobs are parallelized. and then your thread reach the second loop(unless you want to reorganize this code to full parallel version). for the second loop all part of the code can be parallelize.now you should find the percentage of enhancement of each enhanced portion to the serial portion and then find its speedup.